# Is there are any documentation about user-defined menu in midnight-commander?

Tags: mc

I'd like to create my own user-defined menu for mc (**menu** file).
I see some lines like

```
+ t r & ! t t
```

or

```
+ t t
```

What does it mean?

Comment: http://www.softpanorama.org/OFM/MC/user_menu.shtml

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is documented in the help, the node is "Edit Menu File" under "Command Menu"; if you scroll down you should find "Addition Conditions":

> If the condition begins with '+' (or '+?') instead of '=' (or '=?') it
>   is an addition condition. If the condition is true the menu entry will
>   be included in the menu. If the condition is false the menu entry will
>   not be included in the menu.

This is preceded by "Default conditions" (the `=` condition), which determine which entry will be highlighted as the default choice when the menu appears.  Anyway, by way of example:

```
+ t r & ! t t
```

`t r` means if this is a regular file ("t(ype) r"), and `! t t` means if the file has *not* been tagged in the interface.

Answer (score 5):

- Midnight Commander `man`

On top what has been written above, this page can be browsed in the Internet, when searching for man pages, e.g.: https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-mc/

Search for **"Menu File Edit"**.

- Here you could find another good description: http://www.softpanorama.org/OFM/MC/user_menu.shtml

Best regards,
Jarek